# Do we have tetration uniqueness by $ A = \inf \sum_n a_n^2 $?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, functional-equations, taylor-series, tetration

Let $f$ be a real analytic (on at least $|x|<2$) and real solution of the functional equation $f(0) = 1,f(x+1) = \exp(f(x))$. For the existence of such $f$, see [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Complex_heights)

Then
$$
f(x) = \sum_n a_n x^n ;
$$
assume also that $a_n\not= 0$ for all $n\ge 0$.

Let
$$
A = \inf \sum_n a_n^2 ,
$$
with the infimum taken over all such $f$.

Is there a unique $f$ for which $A$ is assumed?

Comment: Are you sure there exists any such $f$?

Comment: It is necessary to state what assumptions are made. This question just states a functional equation without any indication of the fact that this is an assumption.

Comment: @CommandMaster: This indeed seems quite non-trivial, but see this discussion here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Complex_heights

Comment: @CommandMaster yes ! Many analytic solutions to tetration exist. Kneser for instance.

Comment: @DanielAsimov what are you talking about ? No need to justify functional equations. Is the gamma function an assumption ? There are solutions , even analytic ones, so not an assumption required.

Comment: I'm talking about: Are you claiming that there exists an analytic function f(z) satisfying your conditions on the open disk |z| < 2 ?  Are you claiming that your conditions define f(z) uniquely? Or are you asking these things in a question? It is not clear what role your conditions play.

Comment: @DanielAsimov there are infinitely many tetration solutions satisfying analytic on the open disk $|z| < 2$. I am not claiming that , I know that.  I am asking if I have stated a uniqueness criterion by taking the infimum of the sum of squares of the coefficients.

Comment: @mick: I have taken the liberty to rewrite the stylistic aspects of your question, as it did show some inexperience posting on this forum (for example, you can assume that folks here know what an infimum is), and there were some comments on these aspects. Feel free of course to go back or edit further.

Comment: @ChristianRemling no the edit seems fine. Although it did not explain why the radius is at most $2$ although I assume most understand that. Thank you.